# Select data from one table by two fields

Tags: mysql

Structure of my table is

```
item_id (int)
category_id (int)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╗
║ item_id ║ category_id ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║    2    ║      4      ║
║    2    ║      5      ║
║    3    ║      5      ║
║    6    ║      9      ║
║    1    ║      2      ║
║    4    ║      5      ║
║    6    ║      3      ║
║    4    ║      4      ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╝
```

I cant select one row by multiple select by second field.

FOR EXAMPLE, I need to select all rows that include category_id = 4 and 5

Comment: The problem statement is somewhat unclear, at least to me. Could you please share the output you're trying to get for this given sample data?

Comment: @Mureinik need return item_id = 2 and item_id = 4.

Comment: You should give examples of sql statements you have tried in order to get a better understanding of why you can't attain your goal.

Comment: I don't understand the question _or_ the answer.  It just isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Salavat, you seem to be confusing fields with rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/019c4/2

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM items
WHERE category_id IN (4, 5)
GROUP BY item_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id)=2
```